# Duplicate records with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an issue with Hibernate writing duplicate records into a table.
When I check the log, I see:

1. insert into... - 1st insert, which is okay.
2. select... where...
3. insert into... - 2nd insert, not supposed to occur!

What's interesting is that when I set a breakpoint in the code, it works well, and only 1 record is written. Thus, my guess is that Hibernate executes the select query to check whether a record has already been inserted. Then, if I don't have a breakpoint, the code executes fast so the DB/cache is not yet updated (?), so Hibernate gets an empty result, thinks there's no record and executes another insert command. But, if I do have a breakpoint, the DB/cache is updated before the select is executed, so everything is fine.

My question is, what can I do to guarantee that Hibernate always gets the correct DB state? Or, if you think there's another problem here which causes this issue, what can it be?
Thanks.

```
Entity 1: 
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "property2")
private Collection<Entity2>...

Entity 2: 
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="field1",referencedColumnName="field2")
private Entity1...
```

I update by clearing the `collection`, adding all the `Entity2` objects, and then a merge call on the entity manager. However, the situation actually happens when there's no objects in the collection and I just add a new one, so it's not an issue of not clearing properly.

Comment: Post your entity codes and show how you are doing the persists

Comment: @user940016 2nd level will be hit after 1st level cache, if it is running on same thread, it can easily find the one inserted in same 1st level cache, same session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the reason can be:
You have 2 threads:

- 1 Thread - select .. where... _______________insert
- 2 Thread ______________________ insert

Comment: The select is executed after the 1st insert, so it's supposed to get the correct result.